# No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath' when using AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, numpy, aws-lambda

I just uploaded a .zip file to AWS Lambda with all needed packages. I ran all right in my Mac using virtual environment with python 3.8. The AWS Lambda function also has python 3.8. But when I run in AWS Lambda I get this error:

```
No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

I have changed the actual numpy version (1.20.2) to other versions like 1.19.1 and 1.18.5 but the problem can't be fixed.

I am also using spacy 3.0.6 and fastapi 0.63.0.

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: AWS provides a numpy and scipy layer that you can attach once you create the Lambda.(From "Code" page on Lambda Console.) Does the problem persist if you use this layer?

Comment: Yes I know but it has a limit storage space, I tried to import but it wasn't possible

Comment: I guess this was not a lambda running on iOS . numpy uses extensions, which are os-specific. You need to pip-install on the same system as the lambda is running, that is (Amazon) Linux.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am facing the same problem with a custom Lambda Layer I built with GeoLambda.

Answer (score 2):

When I encountered same issue, this steps worked for me:

1- Download required packages(you may need different versions):

```
 - pandas-1.4.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl

   - python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl

   - pytz-2022.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl

 - numpy-1.21.5-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl

 - If you need others ...
```

[image]

2- Create a project folder and unzip whl files to the folder.

3- Remove *dist-info folders.

4- Add your source code to folder(lambda_function.py)

5- Zip the folder and upload to Lambda as a source code zip file.
[image]

Also you can look these links may help you:

https://korniichuk.medium.com/lambda-with-pandas-fd81aa2ff25e
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/13465#issuecomment-545378314

Answer (score 1):

I'm encountering a similar problem. I think the possible reason is that `numpy.core._multiarray_umath` is a compiled binary file relevant to your environment. Incompatible compiled files may lead to this problem. In your case, you may try to compile this file in the same environment as AWS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).